# How to add no margin or padding between images using bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create portfolio section on a one-page site with no margin or no padding in between the images.

How do I achieve this with Bootstrap 3 I tried this but end up with negative margins at tablet/desktop break points:

HTML

```
<!-- Projects Row -->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-one.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-two.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 padding-0 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-three.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-four.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-five.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-six.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-seven.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="../asset/portfolio-work/work-eight.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Field of square images with no gaps between them

Attention! These solutions are not suitable for images of different heights.

---

### 1. HTML-tags are right close to each other

If your images have the same size, you can use even very forthright solution. I've placed all images into one row and removed spaces between them.

Don't forget to remove class `img-responsive` from images. This class adds a property `display: block;`. This property makes all the images stand in a column one above the other.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c69/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/9c6/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/69c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c96/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/6c9/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/96c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c69/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/9c6/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/69c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c96/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/6c9/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/96c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### 2. Media-queries determine the number of images in a row

You can determine the width of images in the same way as the Bootstrap determines the width of columns.

```css
.portfolio {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.portfolio img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 481px)  { .portfolio img { width: 50%; } }
@media (min-width: 768px)  { .portfolio img { width: 33.33%; } }
@media (min-width: 992px)  { .portfolio img { width: 25%; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .portfolio img { width: 20%; } }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 portfolio"><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c69/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/9c6/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/69c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c96/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/6c9/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/96c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c69/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/9c6/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/69c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c96/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/6c9/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a><a
      href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/96c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### 3. Bootstrap Grid

[Neighboring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491697/6263942) offers an excellent solution. Unfortunately, the implementation has stopped after the image size was less than the width of the column.

There are two ways for further work:

1. stretch images to the width of the column
2. select columns whose width is smaller than that of image

The best way is to use both possibilities.

1. Use properties `width: 100%; height: auto;` instead of class `img-responsive` for all images.
2. Let's build a Bootstrap Grid for images of 400 by 400 pixels. Look at [Grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options):

   - phones portrait (less then 481px) → 1 column by `width: 100%;`;
   - phones landscape (less then 768px) → 2 columns by `col-xs-6`;
   - tablets (less then 992px) → 3 columns by `col-sm-4`;
   - desktops (less then 1200px) → 3 columns again;
   - large desktops (1200px and up) → 4 columns by `col-lg-3`.

```css
.portfolio > div {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.portfolio img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  .col-xs-6 { 
    width: 100% !important; 
  } 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row portfolio">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c69/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/9c6/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/69c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c96/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/6c9/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/96c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c69/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/9c6/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/69c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/c96/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/6c9/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/96c/fff/?text=Work" alt=""></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @GlebKemarsky I did your way and it removes the spacing but now there not display inline with each other

Comment: @BrandonPowell What size are your pictures? Maybe they do not fit in one line? What happens if you expand the browser window or increase the scale of screen?

Comment: @BrandonPowell You can determine the width of images in the same way as the Bootstrap determines the width of columns. I've added second code snippet to my answer.

Comment: Hey I have done your idea and it works but for some reason  not inline with each here a screenshot https://gyazo.com/e39a44bccd33c336434b66cc85766ea1

Comment: @BrandonPowell Try to remove `class="img-responsive"`. My solution does not use it.

Comment: @BrandonPowell I rewrote explanations and added a solution by Bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 2):

Every col has a `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px`. Make  **padding: 0** to these cols. Make a new class (e.g. `.myRow`) to not affect the standard classes of Bootstrap. Note that every image must be as big as the width of the cols or bigger!

**HTML**

```
<div class="row myRow">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <a href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/500/sports/1" alt="">
      </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myRow > [class^="col-"] {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what he tried and had issues with negative margins on mobile, due to the .row class accommodating for that padding you are getting rid of. If you use this method, you will want to place this within a media query, which will only be effective on everything above the mobile viewport. For example:

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .myRow > [class^="col-"] {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

Comment: Hey here screenshot of problem that trying to fix https://gyazo.com/fb841de4576606b1acd997e6be08655a @Peter-Leger

Comment: Bootstrap cols have a PADDING of 15px - not a margin. This means that if you have 3 col-md-4's - they will fit across the page but will each have a padding of 15px to the left and the right, meaning that there is a space of 15 px to either side of the first and last col's and a space of 30px between each column. This is why PADDING must be set at 0 to remove said space. Remember that padding is inside an elements border and margin is outside of it. Changing the padding value will have no effect n the margin and vice versa. The row class does not have the padding, which is why is appears wider.

Comment: @gavgrif: You are totally right. That's clear! It was a typo!

Comment: @Brandon Powell: It's because the images don't fit with the width of the column. The width of the images must be wider!

Comment: @PeterLeger I like your solution. I think it's more organic for Bootstrap. I have a solution for problem of small images in wide columns. I've added it to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37491924/6263942) because it contains a huge explanation and a code snippet.

Comment: you guys were very helpful, thank you for helping me

Comment: @BrandonPowell 1. Stack Overflow is a library of questions and answers. Do ask new question if you have another issue. 2. Not sure I understand the problem correctly. Do you want to use the photo as the background for the text? Try to draw a picture or describe in more detail what you need.